# how to compare two elements in priority_queue

Tags: c++

I defined a `priority_queue<pair<double, int>>`. The smaller double value has higher priority.  If there are several same double values in the queue, then pop one randomly.  For example: `(<0.1, 1>, <0.1,2>, <0.1, 0>,<0.1,5>)`, how to pop one of them randomly?  I am not sure if my idea is reasonable. Because the location of the element has been determined ,when it is pushed into the queue.

Comment: Since you are using a `std::pair` the `int` part of the pare is also used when sorting the elements in the queue

Comment: Are you asking how to choose one element randomly among the ones with the same `double` value? If so: since the underlying container is not exposed, you can either pop the values with the same `double` and choose one or roll your own version. Not sure I understood what you're asking

Comment: Queues in computer science is very much like queues in real life, stuff goes in at one and and out at the other. This means that there's really no way to access elements randomly.

Comment: Actually, I used this in shortest path computation.  If I have same double values (distance to src),  but from different int (node id), I just want to randomly select a node id. That's what I want.

Answer (score 2):

If by "randomly" you mean it should perform a real (pseudo)random selection among all items with the lowest value of the `double`, then that is not something `std::priority_queue` can do for you—it was not designed for that. Your best bet would be to pop and save all items while their priority is the same, then select one randomly and re-insert the rest into the queue.

If, on the other hand, you mean "random" as in "any one of them is good," then you can simply do that with a custom comparator which will only consider the value of the `first` data member of the pair. Which one gets popped when these agree will depend on the internal implementation of the priority queue (and possibly on insertion order as well). For many purposes, this could be "random" enough.

In code, the second option would look like this:

```
struct DoublePriority
{
  bool operator() (const std::pair<double, int> &lhs, const std:pair<double, int> &rhs) const {
    return lhs.first > rhs.first;
  }
};

std::priority_queue<std::pair<double, int>, std::vector<std::pair<double, int>>, DoublePriority> theQueue;
```

Comment: I used this method before. But now it always select the pair with larger node id.  I used this in computing shortest path.   If I have same double values (distance to src), but from different int (node id), I just want to randomly select a node id and pop that pair accordingly.  Maybe I should change my method, the priority_queue is not designed for this.

Answer (score 2):

You could store tuples `double, int, int`, where the last term is a unique random number your comparator will use to resolve comparisons of equivalent elements.